# How to create intrument to add point to database from user click?

Tags: python, web, leaflet, gis, geodjango

I want to create control on my Django project which allows me to click on map and store result to postgreSQL database.
I've achieved what I want through /admin panel, but how can I run it from user page ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN2VS.png)

Also there is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels

class Point_Creation(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
location = geomodels.PointField()
```

admin.py

```
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Point_Creation


admin.site.register(Point_Creation, LeafletGeoAdmin)
```

Comment: Which map are you using?

Comment: I'm using leaflet with leaflet-geodjango extension